# Assign core.mul.mul to an entry of sympy.Matrix

Tags: python, sympy

I have a question below:

When the variable "temp" is assigned to a row of the MutableDenseMatrix, an error pops up:

**ValueError: unexpected value:** x1*x3**2

But the product is what I need. Is there a type conversion issue? Tons of thanks.

```
import numpy as np
import sympy as sp
Y = sp.MutableDenseMatrix(sp.zeros(3,1))
temp = 1
x = sp.symbols('x:'+str(4))
X = sp.Matrix(x)
C = np.array([0, 1, 0, 2])
for i in range(X.shape[0]):
    temp = temp * sp.Pow(X[i], C[i])
    
Y[1,:] = temp
```

Answer (score 1):

When you use slice notation on a symbolic matrix, the value you are going to assign needs to be an iterable, even though you are going to assign a single element. For example, this works:

```
Y[1,:] = [temp]
```

Alternatively, since `Y` is a single column matrix and with `Y[1,:]` you are targeting a single value, you can do:

```
Y[1] = temp
```

Comment: Don't forget to mark this answer as the solution to your question!